# Animate a line on matlab

Tags: matlab, animation

I would like to animate a self updating plot on matlab. For example a string vibrating between two ends. All the basic animate functions I have found in the documentation accomplish the same thing, mainly to animate an *evolving* plot. I.e the function remains the same but the number of points plotted increases (or decreases) in time. For example this script:

```
h = animatedline;
axis([0,4*pi,-1,1])

x = linspace(0,4*pi,1000);
y = sin(x);
for k = 1:length(x)
    addpoints(h,x(k),y(k));
    drawnow
end
```

traces a sine function as if an invisible hand was drawing it. What I would like to do is animate the entire function but with a varying parameter, like the phase or amplitude. I tried to modify using the following:

```
x = linspace(0,4*pi,1000);

;
axis([0,4*pi,-1,1])

for k = 1:10
    h = animatedline(x,sin(k*x))
    drawnow
end
```

This is sort of close to what I need but the functions are progressively appended, not replaced. This results in a total of 10 functions being plotted instead of an animation.

Does anyone understand what I need to do? If so how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
h = animatedline;
axis([0,4*pi,-1,1]);

x = linspace(0,4*pi,1000);

for k = 1:0.01:10
    y = sin(k*x);
    clearpoints(h);        
    addpoints(h,x,y);
    drawnow 
end
```

Comment: Nice one. I was going crazy trying to adapt the `movie` command (https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movie.html). This is more straightforward. Is there a way to control how **fast** it plots?

Comment: A simple trick is to play with the step. k=1:0.001:10 will be slower. Another option is to include time-check commands such as: a = tic; b = toc(a); if b < (1/25) %do something

Comment: @user32882 please accept the answer if it is correct.

Comment: Regarding the speed. I suppose that you have seen the docs: https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/animatedline-object.html