# Generating variable amount of animatedlines and plotting simultaneously in Matlab

Tags: matlab, animation

I have improved upon the code in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44754446/animate-a-line-on-matlab) using the `animatedline` object in Matlab. Now I am creating two animated lines that represent different time dependent functions and plotting them simultaneously:

```
h1 = animatedline('Color' , 'r');
h2  = animatedline('Color' , 'b');

axis([0,4*pi,-1,1]);

x = linspace(0,4*pi,1000);

for k = 1:0.01:3
    y1 = sin(k*x);
    y2 = sin(k*x/2)

    clearpoints(h1);   
    clearpoints(h2)

    addpoints(h1,x,y1);
    addpoints(h2,x,y2);

    drawnow 
end
```

I would like to generalize this even further. What I really need is to generate `n` amount of animated lines where `n` is specified by the user. Then I would like to animate each of these lines in a loop that is somehow sensitive to the number of animated lines.

In the above code I am declaring a separate object for each animatedline. I really don't see how it would be possible to extend this to a variable amount of animated lines?

Comment: Hi user32882. How did you get on with the answer below?

Comment: I have not investigated the answer yet. I will do so when I have some time and when it becomes relevant again to my work.

Comment: Nevertheless, would you acknowledge the person who has helped you?

Comment: Ok, I have voted them up

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work:

```
% User input
n = 5;

colors = lines(n);
h(1 : n) = animatedline();
for n_param = 1 : n
    h(n_param) = animatedline('Color' , colors(n_param , :));
end

axis([0,4*pi,-1,1]);

x = linspace(0,4*pi,1000);

for k = 1:0.01:3
    for n_param = 1 : n
        % Do something with the parameter
        y = sin(k*x/n_param);

        h(n_param).clearpoints();       
        h(n_param).addpoints(x,y);
    end
    drawnow 
end
```

I used an array to store the handles of the animatedlines objects, set them up with individual colours and plotted them in a for loop.