# Implementation of animatedline command to animate two lines simultaneously

Tags: matlab, animation

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44754446/animate-a-line-on-matlab/44754837#44754837) in which I was trying to animate two functions simultaneously. The solution provided did in fact fulfill the requirements and so I accepted it as a final answer.

However, I ran into additional problems when I tried to implement something similar for my more realistic case. The intent of the code below is to:

- Generate a 3d matrix containing incrementally (linear) varying stress values named `Stresses`. The first index is for the incrementally varying values, the second index corresponds to each value in `Depth` matrix and the third index corresponds to each `animatedline` object
- Generate a 2D matrix named `Depth` containing two rows. each row corresponds to an `animatedline`.
- Plot the animated lines and animate simultaneously

  ```
  %%PLOT AND ANIMATE
  nlines = 2
  h(1:nlines) = animatedline();

  axis([-2.1,2,-10,0]);

  for i = 1:100
      for j = 1:3
          Stresses(i,j,1) = (i/100)+j/3
          Stresses(i,j,2) = -(i/100)-j/3
      end
  end

  Depth = [0, -5, -10; 0,-6,-9]

  for i = 1:size(Stresses,1)
      for n = 1:nlines
          n
          currentStresses = Stresses(i,:,n)
          h(n).clearpoints();        
          h(n).addpoints(currentStresses, Depth(n,:));
          %pause(0.01) 
      end
      drawnow
  end
  ```

As far as I can tell this uses a similar format to the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44754446/animate-a-line-on-matlab/44754837#44754837) question. Including the `pause` statement results in simultaneous but "Choppy" plotting. Not including the `pause` statement results smooth but "non-simultaneous" plotting. I.e it plots only the second line.

I would like for the animation to be smooth and simultaneously plot both `animatedline` objects. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simultaneous plotting, you are missing the [`hold`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) function.

```
close all
%%PLOT AND ANIMATE
nlines = 2;
% optional: so that you can distinguish between the two lines
colors = {'r','b'};
for n = 1:nlines
    h(n) = animatedline('color',colors{n});
end

axis([-2.1,2,-10,0]);

for i = 1:50
    for j = 1:3
        Stresses(i,j,1) = (i/100)+j/3;
        Stresses(i,j,2) = -(i/100)-j/3;
    end
end

Depth = [0, -5, -10; 0,-6,-9];

for i = 1:size(Stresses,1)
    for n = 1:nlines
        n;
        currentStresses = Stresses(i,:,n);
        h(n).clearpoints();        
        h(n).addpoints(currentStresses, Depth(n,:));
        % wait for another line
        hold on
    end
    % clear hold
    hold off
    drawnow
end
```

Hope that helps!